# Using SELECT * FROM col WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table set up for keywords.  columns are -

> keywordID | keyword1 | keyword2 | keyword3 | keyword4 | questionID

I want to provide functionality through a website for a user to find a question and edit it.  I'm thinking the best way to do this currently is to have the user search for the question by entering keywords.  When I use

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword1="first_search_word"
```

it works, but when I try the same but

```
WHERE keyword2="first_search_word"
```

it doesn't return any, even though they exist.  I also tried using `OR` (or `||` ) but couldn't find anything about that either.

Comment: So.. you have a column for keyword1, and it works when used for comparison against the column 'keyword1', and you also have another column 'ky2', but it doesn't work when you use 'keyword2'..  I think the answer is kind of obvious.  Use 'ky2' instead of 'keyword2'.

Comment: @connor Be a litle bit more specific and descriptive!

Comment: Having keyword1 thru 4 smells like a database anti pattern that violates the first normal form.

Answer (score 4):

What is keywordID in relation to keyword1?

Anyway, this isn't the right way to approach your problem.  It sounds like you wants tags where every question can be associated with multiple tags, right?  This is known as a many-to-many relation and will require more than 1 table.  You will need:

- A tags table with 2 columns, tagId and tag
- A questions table with at least 2 columns, questionId and question
- A tags_questions join table with 2 columns, tagId and questionId.

To look up what questions have a certain tag, first look up the tagId in the tags table.  Then do a `SELECT questionId from tags_questions where tagId = $tagId`.  To do the lookup based on a keyword not a specific tag you can do `SELECT questionId FROM tags_questions WHERE tagId IN (SELECT tagId FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE "%{$keyword}%")`.

Comment: +1 I suspect that keywordID is the unique primary key of the keywords table.  I also agree that the requirement calls for a many-to-many relation.  In your example, you could use the literal keyword instead of tags to keep connor's keyword thinking.

Answer (score 1):

> When I using
>
> `SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword1="first_search_word"`
>
> it works, but when I try the same but
>
> `WHERE keyword2="first_search_word"`
>
> it doesn't return any

But you also say

> columns are keywordID, keyword1, ky2, ky3, ky4, questionID

So you dont actually have a column called `keyword2` so it would not be surprising there are no matches. Unless of course you have mistyped some values in your question - and should that be the case you should rewrite your question